# field not saved when I change the name attribute of the field form in Yii

Tags: html, yii

when I add the name attribute to a field form in Yii ,  the field content is not saved in DB

the following works,

```
echo $form->textField($model,'country'); ?>
```

it generates the html code

```
<input name="RegistrationForm[country]" id="RegistrationForm_country" type="text" maxlength="50" />
```

the following does not work,

```
echo $form->textField($model,'country', array('name'=>'country'); ?>
```

it generates the html code

```
<input name="country" id="country" type="text" maxlength="50" />
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `name="RegistrationForm[country]"` is required if you are using

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['RegistrationForm'];
```

to set the attributes in the controller.

If you want to use a custom name like `name="country"`, you will have to manually set the value of the model yourself:

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['RegistrationForm'];
$model->country = $_POST['country'];
```